# Building python 3.6.6 from source on Win10

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, compilation, windows-10

I've downloaded the python 3.6.6 source from here...
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-366/
...and followed the instruction on how to build on Windows (run ../PCbuild/build.bat). Python compiles and seems to be working (funny and scary: while fetching externals, it actually downloads python-3.7.0 as a dependency... :/ ). However, it looks like the build is somehow 'in place', and the binaries end up in some sub-folder of the source (../PCbuild/amd64/python.exe). This means I'm left with source and compiled code mixed up instead of some clean/lean and deployable package.

- can I somehow provide '`--prefix=/target/build/path`' to define a target location to build to, like I would on linux?
- is there a way of removing all src files/folders and leave only the required files/folders (../lib, ../include, etc...).

Or in general, is there a way of making the build process more behave like on linux?

Thanks for your help,
Max

Comment: `--prefix=/target/build/path` is false, `--prefix=/target/INSTALL/path`. "*and the binaries end up in some sub-folder of the source*": same thing happens on every platform.

Answer (score 1):

The build.bat from PCBuild is intended for developers, that is, for testing purposes. What you want is under `\Tools\msi\buildrelease.bat`. This creates a subdirectory under `\PCBuild\` that places all msi, cab and exe files ready for later installation. According to the readme, there doesn't seem to be an option to pack all those files in a single .exe file, like all installers eventually do, but another option is under `\Tools\msi\build.bat` which does have an option for packing (namely `build.bat --pack`). "**But**", the readme does state that the `buildrelease.bat` should be used for an official release. The advantage of doing so is that Pyhton would be optimized using PGO to your own hardware. I am also trying to compile from source using this method but I am having an issue with a recurring error (and other ones):

```
PGO run did not succeed (no python36!*.pgc files) and there is no data to merge [E:\RepoGiT\3.6\PCbuild\pythoncore.vcxproj]
```

so, if you do go this route, and find this, or other errors, please send the bug report to python's bug tracker [webpage](https://bugs.python.org). And better yet, if you find errors and their solution, please report back here!

Comment: As a sidenote, it appears that the development team is more focused on Linux installs. You can get a response if you report a bug using windows but from my personal experience you only get that: the acknowledgment of it. The actual bug tracking is far less common, maybe because the amount of users building from source on a windows machine are far less that the ones compiling to linux based computers. I think it is assumed the majority of windows users install pyhton using the provided official installers. Maybe if more people using windows are involved, we could get more presence there.